# "Open" home security systems

Tags: home-security, interoperability

Is there a security system that allows input signals from different providers / systems and aggregates them? For example, it can use presence / motion sensors coming from ecobee and echo flex, ring doorbell and blink outdoor cameras, nest CO/Smoke detectors, etc. (and not necessarily these brands, those were the first that came to mind)? I have quite a few IoT devices, and I'd like them to work in ensemble. I'd also want to choose the best for each task, but have them work together (through a hub that I pay a monitoring service for) to paint a coherent picture of the house state.

I'm a software engineer and a hacker at heart, so I don't mind creating complicated IFTTT or similar scripts -- or even programming and paying for a lambda function -- to achieve that goal.

Comment: control4.com ? Or are you looking for something that's more hands on ?

Comment: I didn't know about control4.com, and it's really interesting. But what I wanted is a home security system that had professional monitoring but didn't lock me into their devices, except for the main hub, maybe the door / window opening sensors.

I don't mind hands on, but hands off is better.

Comment: Another company to look at is scoutalarm.com Let us know if that worked for you.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, you could do everything else via IFTTT except the last part of calling the cops. You could send yourself a text via twilio and have your local PD phone number in your pocket. But you maybe asleep ! I guess you could have IFTTT close a switch which ultimately causes an alarm in some common burgler alarm system that has monitoring service !